# usar google maps em meu site

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Olá, estou com um sistema , e preciso cada vez que abrir esta box , mudar o endereço do google maps de acordo com o endereço que aparecer de cada registro como segue na foto : 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto é uma box que mostra varias informações de um registro , e um dos resultados do registro é o local, como eu faria para mudar o maps de acordo com este endereço ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais fácil será possivelmente utilizando um iframe e PHP.

`<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.it/maps?q=<?php echo $localizacao; ?>&output=embed"></iframe>`

Substitui a `$localizacao` pela tua variável de localização e faz os ajustes necessários para a dimensão do iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode deixar de padrão no formulário: `https://www.google.com.br/maps/search/`, e inserir o código da consulta no DB em sequência com `echo` como no resto da página.

Exemplo: `https://www.google.com.br/maps/search/<?php echo $consulta['mapa'];?>/`